# Convert a 'DeseqStats' object into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: bioinformatics, rna-seq, sequencing

Is it possible to convert a DeseqStats object from PyDESeq2 into a Pandas DataFrame?

`results_summary = stat_res results_as_html = results_summary.tables[1].as_html() pd.read_html(results_as_html, header=0, index_col=0)[0]`

It resulted in an attribute error: 'DeseqStats' object has no attribute 'tables'

Answer (score 0):

`de = stat_res.results_df` should work :)